# How to use credentials from other files and how to pass dir locations in crons?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, unix

I was written a script for My database backup.Now i want to pass user name and password from other config file (i mean i want to use credentials from other config file) how can use it?

From the cron i want to pass backupdir path.how we able to pass variables in the cron ?

EXample of my cron

```
/usr/local/bin/cronwrap -m host:mlora-pc-bkp.prod.hdkind.com "/usr/bin/mysql-zrm-backup --backup-set mlora_pc --backup-level 0 --socket /var/untd/mysql/mlora/tmp/mysql.sock  > /tmp/mysql-zrm-backup_iflora.out 2>&1" "mysql-zrm-backup" penxttx@hdkind.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just to add a file in your home directory and it will disable the mysqldump password prompting. This is done by creating the file ~/.my.cnf (permissions need to be 600).

Add this to the .my.cnf file

```
[mysqldump]
user=mysqluser
password=secret
```

This lets you connect as a MySQL user who requires a password without having to actually enter the password. You don't even need the -p or --password.

Very handy for scripting mysql & mysqldump commands.

Comment: i was written a shell script with seperate backup user

Comment: You can put that that user and password in this file